# Вопрос по паттерну ActiveRecord

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, activerecord

В `Active Record` объектный экземпляр привязан к единственной строке в таблице.

Как можно тогда объяснить такие методы? Ведь они не соответствуют записи в бд?

Джойны

```
$book = Book::all(array('joins' => array('author')));
sql => SELECT `books`.* FROM `books`
    INNER JOIN `authors` ON(`books`.author_id = `authors`.id)
```

Агрегатные функции

```
Book::find('all', array('select' => 'avg(price) as avg_price, avg(tax) as avg_tax'));
sql => SELECT avg(price) as avg_price, avg(tax) as avg_tax FROM `books` LIMIT 5,10
```

Группировка

```
Book::all(array('group' => 'price'));
sql => SELECT * FROM `books` GROUP BY price
```

Группировка + `having`

```
Book::all(array('group' => 'price', 'having' => 'price > 45.00'));
sql => SELECT * FROM `books` GROUP BY price HAVING price > 45.00
```

Или же вообще нативный запрос

```
$book = Book::find_by_sql('select title from `books`');
```

Объясните пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Всё довольно просто. В таких случаях вы выбираете не одну модель, а сразу коллекцию моделей (или массив). Например, в известном фреймворке Laravel имеется возможность получить сразу несколько моделей следующим образом:

```
$models = Model::where('id', '>', '2')->get();
```

Здесь выберутся все модели, id которых больше двух. Вернутся они в виде коллекции моделей (если вас смущает нестандартное для PHP слово коллекция - считайте, что это "массивы на стероидах").

Comment: Коллекция - это всё таки больше массив объектов, или объект содержащий объекты, которые по сути содержат объекты. И на сколько мне известно eloquen формирует два запроса а не join, и по это в объекте коллекции есть параметры которые содержат связанные данные.

Comment: Бесспорно, но человек не спрашивал про Коллекции, поэтому я решил это не расписывать подробно:) Думаю, если у него будет желание узнать про коллекции больше - он либо почитает, либо спросит.